# Use jQuery to dynamically change class values based on field values

Tags: jquery

Here are the different parts of my code

part1

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a class="tab1" href=""></a></li>
  <li><a class="tab2" href=""></a></li>
  <li><a class="tab3" href=""></a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

and part2

```
<div class="field-items">
  <div class="field-item">tab1</div>
  <div class="field-item">tab3</div>
  ...
</div>
```

How to make a condition so that if in Part 2 it has the values "tab1" and "tab3", then Part 1 is modified to contain these classes:

```
<li class="hiden"><a class="tab1" href=""></a></li>
...
<li class="hiden"><a class="tab3" href=""></a></li>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.field-items div.field-item").each(function(){
       $("." + $(this).html()).parent().addClass("hiden");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. And how do if such a relationship?<li><a class="tab1" href="">111</a></li> and part2 <div class="field-item">111</div>

Comment: Would you correct this `.jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('.field-item').each(function()
{
    var tabname = $(this).text();
    if(tabname == 'tab1' || tabname == 'tab3')
 {
  $('.tabs li a').hasClass(tabname).parent().addClass("hiden");
 }
});
})`.

Comment: @Siteogra: It can be done easily by adding a selector `:econtains` to jQuery. I've set up an example forking your last jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5RzxN/1/ Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
$('.field-item').each(function()
{
    $('.' + this.innerHTML).addClass('hiden');
});
```

Maybe a little bit of modification, but should do the trick.